# Using model inheritance, how could you order two different models differently in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a model named Photo and a model named Video. They both inherit off a model named Item, which contains the a time_created field and item_by field. I know that you can order objects from these two different models by using `Item.objects.all().order_by('time_created')`. However, I'd like to order Photo by time and Video by rank. I would still like to group these two objects under one queryset, even if they are ordered differently, so that I could display it on one page (like a grid). How would I be able to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know you can accomplish something similar by overriding the child models `Meta ordering` property. However without seeing your model code (proxy, abstract etc.) I can't say for certain if this will work for you.

```
class Item(models.Model):
    time_created = models.DateField()
    rank = models.IntegerField()


class Photo(Item):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['time_created']


class Video(Item):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['rank']
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try real soon. So if I call Item.objects.all(), if Item 1 and 3 are photos and Item 2 and 4 are videos, Item 1 will be created after item 3 and item 2 will have a higher rank than item 4?